# Mysql count row left

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a database table of keys, let's say about 200 keys in the table.

table keys: id | keys | sent

Every time a key is sent, the row of the key sent will equal to true.

I want to do a query that check the table. If the table keys has 10% keys left, an email will be sent to my boss to allow him to put more keys in the database.

I am newbie with sql. Should I do a query of join table or count row??

Any help or suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_keys, SUM(IF(sent, 1, 0)) AS used_keys
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: if it's mysql, this can be further simplified into `SUM(sent = 1)`. `:D`

Comment: I'm assuming 'sent' is a bit field, so I'm just coercing that bit into the equivalent 1 or 0 integers, which get summed up. if sent is "false", it'll become a 0 and not count against the "used" sum.

Comment: I try it but I got a error. select count(id) as total_keys, sum(if(used,1,0) as used_keys) from product_keys;